# Movie where a group of people travel back in time to the age of the dinosaurs. A woman is kidnapped by giant spiders, which put eggs in her stomach

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I saw a movie about 8 years ago and the group went back in time to the age of the dinosaurs. At the end of the movie, one of the characters gets kidnapped and the giant spiders put eggs in her stomach. When she goes to run, her stomach explodes and the baby spiders come out.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra info you remember? Could you try remember when it was released? Was it a low budget film? How many people were in the group?

Answer (score 15):

Possibly *Journey to the Center of the Earth* (2008), not to be mistaken with the movie starring Brendan Fraser which got released the same year.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1231575):

> A California research institute is performing a teleportation experiment to send their military research team to Stuttgart, Germany. But **something goes wrong, and the team ends up at the center of the earth, where they just manage to send off a distress signal before being hunted by a dinosaur.** Joseph Harnet, head scientist in CA, contacts Emily Radford, sister of the missing unit's leader and head of a deep bore drill experiment, for help in rescuing the stranded team. The two mount a rescue operation, drilling down to the earth's core to save the girls before it's too late. In the mean time the stranded group are doing their best to survive in the deadly environment.

The [Parents Guide](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1231575/parentalguide/violence) lists this bit as a spoiler (so it could be taking place at the end of movie):

> **A character vomits up blood and spider eggs after being wrapped in a giant spider's web. Later, the person's stomach graphically explodes, and baby spiders begin crawling out.** Blood sprays everywhere, including onto another character. This scene is extremely graphic for a PG-13 movie, but it is fairly brief.

The trailer also contains spiders:

---

Found with the Google query `scifi movie time travel dinosaurs spider eggs stomach site:imdb.com/title` which returned, among others, the parental guide quoted above.

Comment: There were THREE "Journey to the Center of the Earth"s released in 2008?! How is that possible? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_Center_of_the_Earth_(disambiguation)

Comment: @Brad - One of them is by The Asylum - a studio whose entire business model is beating blockbusters to the punch with cheap knock-offs.  Normally they change the name slightly (e.g. *Transmorphers*), but in this case the original novel is old enough they don't have to since it's in public domain.